SSIS Connection Manager for OData, cannot find Version 14.100.0.0 anywhere
I have two different SSIS solutions: Misc SSIS Packages and BusRoutesDataTransform.  I generally develop new packages in Misc SSIS Packages and when it is complete, add the package to it's new production home, in this case BusRoutesDataTransform.  I created my first OData source package and it took some wrangling, but eventually I got everything working.  After I added it to BusRoutesDataTransform, I get the following error when I Test Connection of the OData source:

Some investigation revealed that the two solutions have a different version of the OData connection.  The one that works, Misc SSIS Packages, is using Version 14.1 and BusRoutesDataTransform is using version 11.0. Below are the Connection Managers for Misc SSIS Packages and BusRoutesDataTransform, respectively:

I'm assuming this is the issue. I have been looking for the SSIS OData Connection File Version 14.1 and cannot find it anywhere.  I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 and have tried installing several different SSIS packages, but none of them have helped. Googling for SSIS OData Connection Manager 14.1 keeps taking me to a page that wants me to download 2022 SQL Server, which I finally did, and even that didn't help.
What can I try next?
